# How do I change precision of float values in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Hello in my database I have a column with numbers such as 6.251543423 I want to make them like 6.25 without rounding them.

I've tried `update examresults set point = substring(point,0,5)` but it returned all values as zero

Comment: `cast(point as decimal(10, 2))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to round you must truncate:

```
TRUNCATE(6.251543423,2)
```

When you `CAST` as `DECIMAL(n,2)` or `FLOAT(n,2)` the result will be rounded.

Comment: I casted and it didnt round my values e.g my value was 95.3125 and result is 95.31

Comment: @Rodrane: Try `95.3155`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the floating point values to DECIMAL datatype, with appropriate number of digits after the decimal point.  In this example, two digits after the decimal point.

```
SELECT CONVERT(float_col,DECIMAL(65,2)) AS dec_col 
  FROM ...
```

The floating point types FLOAT and DOUBLE are approximate decimal values. They are stored in standard IEEE floating point representation.

If you convert to decimal, and then store that back in a floating point column, it will be converted back into floating point representation.

You would need to do the conversion to DECIMAL when you pull the value back out again.

If you want to store an exact decimal representation, you would need to store the value in a column defined as DECIMAL (or NUMERIC) datatype, not a FLOAT or DOUBLE.

---

Also...

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example,

(that's excerpted from MySQL Reference Manual:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html )

(NOTE: I've never exercised/tested that behavior of `DOUBLE(18,2)`. When we need exact decimals, we use DECIMAL. And when we need floating point, we use plain old DOUBLE.)